# scrapy result only save one item in a loop

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from universities.items import UniversitiesItem


def clean_full_name(full_name):
    sp = full_name.split(',')
    last_name = sp[0].strip()
    first_name = sp[1].replace('\r\n', '').strip()
    first_name = ' '.join(first_name.split()[:-1]).strip()
    return ' '.join([last_name, first_name])


class DerexlUniversity(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'drexel_university'
    allowed_domains = ['drexel.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://drexel.edu/search?t=people&q=']

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('kw.txt') as file_object:
            last_names = file_object.readlines()

        for ln in ['Chong', 'Zhao']:
            self.last_name = ln.strip()
            print('-----------------------------------------------------')
            print("scraping last name: ", self.last_name)
            query = response.url + self.last_name
            yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('This is item page %s', self.last_name)
        result_rows = response.xpath('//table//tr[@class="result-row"]')
        result_details = response.xpath('//table//tr[@class="result-details"]')

        for row, detail in zip(result_rows, result_details):
            full_name = row.xpath('.//span[@class="fullname"]/text()').extract_first()
            if full_name:
                full_name = clean_full_name(full_name)
                if self.last_name in full_name.split():
                    item = UniversitiesItem()
                    item['fullname'] = full_name
                    item['university'] = 'Drexel University'
                    try:
                        item['email'] = row.xpath('.//span[@class="email-address"]/a/@href').extract_first()[7:]
                        item['phone'] = row.xpath('.//span[@class="phone-numbers"]/a/@href').extract_first()[4:]

                        person_detail = detail.xpath('.//span[@class="person-detail"]/text()').extract()
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                    else:
                        person_detail_clean = ', '.join([pd.strip() for pd in person_detail[0].split(',')][1:])
                        item['person_detail'] = person_detail_clean

                    yield item
```

There are 2 key words in the for loop, which is 'Chong' and 'Zhao'. I tried to save the result in a CSV file. I generate a new item every time in the for loop in the parse_item function. However, only 'Zhao' is being saved. I can't figure it out why.

Comment: I checked and Chong has no results

Comment: [http://drexel.edu/search?t=people&q=chong](http://drexel.edu/search?t=people&q=chong) There are 166 matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues is related to `self.last_name`. You should not be using class level variables across responses. You should `response.meta` instead. Below works for me

```
class DerexlUniversity(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'drexel_university'
    allowed_domains = ['drexel.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://drexel.edu/search?t=people&q=']

    def parse(self, response):
        # with open('kw.txt') as file_object:
        #     last_names = file_object.readlines()

        for ln in ['Chong', 'Zhao']:
            last_name = ln.strip()
            print('-----------------------------------------------------')
            print("scraping last name: ", last_name)
            query = response.url + last_name
            yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_item, meta=dict(last_name=last_name))

    def parse_item(self, response):
        last_name = response.meta['last_name']
        self.logger.info('This is item page %s', last_name)
        result_rows = response.xpath('//table//tr[@class="result-row"]')
        result_details = response.xpath('//table//tr[@class="result-details"]')

        for row, detail in zip(result_rows, result_details):
            full_name = row.xpath('.//span[@class="fullname"]/text()').extract_first()
            if full_name:
                full_name = clean_full_name(full_name)
                if last_name in full_name.split():
                    item = {}
                    item['fullname'] = full_name
                    item['university'] = 'Drexel University'
                    try:
                        item['email'] = row.xpath('.//span[@class="email-address"]/a/@href').extract_first()[7:]
                        item['phone'] = row.xpath('.//span[@class="phone-numbers"]/a/@href').extract_first()[4:]

                        person_detail = detail.xpath('.//span[@class="person-detail"]/text()').extract()
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                    else:
                        person_detail_clean = ', '.join([pd.strip() for pd in person_detail[0].split(',')][1:])
                        item['person_detail'] = person_detail_clean

                    yield item
```

Comment: Cool, it works. But I still don't understand why a class level variable doesn't work.

Comment: Because by the time you reach `parse_item` value of `self.last_name` is `Zhao`, the last one. Scrapy is not running your methods sequentially hence you should not share variables across functions like this. That is why you should be using meta which can passed with the response